# how to update key/value database with laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I'm just learning laravel. I want update key / value in database with laravel api but not work.

My `products` model is one to many with `ProductMeta` and many to many with `contents` model.

##### My Models

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function productMeta()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductMeta::class);
    }

    public function content()
    {
        return  $this->belongsToMany(Content::class, 'product_contents')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

```php
class ProductMeta extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Content extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded= [];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_contents');
    }
```

##### Controller

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

     DB::table('product_metas')
        ->upsert(
            [
                [
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'key' => 'name',
                    'value' => $request->name,
                ],
                [
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => $request->name,
                ],
                [
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'key' => 'amount',
                    'value' => $request->name,
                ],
            ],
            ['product_id','key'],
            ['value']
        );

    return \response()->json([], 204);
}
```

##### Table Structure

[image: databasee]

##### API parameter

[image: Postman]

I tried with `update` and `updateOrcreate` and `updateOrInsert` and `upsert` methods.

just in upsert method writed database but inserted new data.not updated.

[image: database 2]

Comment: Put a unique key on your metadata table - `$table->unique(['product_id', 'key'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem solved this way:

```php
    ProductMeta::query()->where('product_id', $id)->upsert([
    ['product_id' => $id, 'key' => 'name', 'value' => $request->name],
    ['product_id' => $id, 'key' => 'price', 'value' => $request->price],
    ['product_id' => $id, 'key' => 'amount', 'value' => $request->amount]],
    ['product_id'], ['value']);
    
    $contentRecord = Product::find($id);
    $contentRecord->content()->update(['path'=>$request->path]);
                
        return response()->json([], 204);
```

I forget use query() method for ProductMeta and added  `$table->unique(['product_id', 'key']);` to product meta migration.

**products relation one to many with product Meta
And Many to many with content.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use `updateOrCreate()` instead of `upsert`.

```php
Product::updateOrCreate([
  'product_id' => $id,
  'name' => $request->name,
  'price' => $request->price,
  'amount' => $request->amount
]);
```

or

```php
Product::upsert([
  [
    'product_id' => $id,
    'name' => $request->name,
    'price' => $request->price,
    'amount' => $request->amount
  ]
], ['product_id'], ['name', 'price', 'amount']);
```

In addition your problem is your table name is not matching with your structure table name. In your controller `DB::table('product_metas')` should be `DB::table('products_meta')`.

Comment: upsert method not work for me in eloquent
because inserted data instead of Updating.

Comment: I still think it work for you, and add more code details to my answer, just attention that you are trying to use multiple row method upsert instead of single row method updateOrCreate.